# Creating a function with multiple arguments

Tags: r, function

```
> Test
    param1  param2  param3
1   300      78      98
2   357      539     NA
3   4859     NA      NA
```

So imagine I have a dataframe like that for example. I want to write a function which takes as its arguments the following: Variable names as characters strings, the data as a data.frame, and the maximum number of NA answer per respondent.

So the function would work something along the lines of

`test1<-test_function(c("param2", "param3"), data = Test, max_NA = 1)`

And it would return something like:

```
   test1    
1  78 + 98            
2   539           
3   NA
```

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What does the max_NA do?

Comment: @Kristofersen It is the max amount of NA answers allowed per respondent.

Comment: are you sure you dont just want an option to ignore NAs? That seems easier to me

Comment: @Kristofersen I guess, if you can even help me get started that would be amazing, I have been trying to crack this nut all day hah!

Comment: the code i have below should get you started. If you want to include max_NA you could sum the number of NAs in the df by doing something like `rowSums(is.na(df))`. Then, use that value to filter out specific rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_function = function(df, Columns, ...){
  rowSums(df[, Columns], ...)
}

Columns = c("param2", "param3")

> test_function(df, Columns)
  1   2   3 
176  NA  NA 
> test_function(df, Columns, na.rm = T)
  1   2   3 
176 539   0
```